# How do I blur whatever is behind a translucent UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a translucent png image (made by turning down the opacity in Photoshop), and there's a UIImageView behind that translucent image. Is there any way to blur the parts of the UIImageView on the bottom that intersect with the UIImageView on top? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not aware of any code that will do that on its own, but you could 'fake it' by rendering the intersection of the views in a graphics context, then [apply a blur effect to it](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/uiimage-blur.html).  Then you could take the graphics context and insert a UIImageView with the resulting image in between the two views to simulate the effect.  This method would not work very well if you have any sort of animation or otherwise changing the state of the images.

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting alpha of the image to less than 1.